# CA service DESK REST api using JAVA

Tags: java, rest

Our infra team set up the ca service desk in machine and share the details. I need to make rest call to create the incident from java program. And here i want to use basic authentication by providing the access key. For this I tried to make the end point url to get the access key and after that to create incident as shown below.

> http://Host:port/caisd-rest/rest_access
>   http://CAdeskHost:port/caisd-rest/in

```
    String endpoint = "http://host:port/caisd-rest/rest_access";
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    String encodedCredentials = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(("username" + ":" + "password").getBytes()));
    PostMethod post = new PostMethod(endpoint);
    post.addRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
    post.addRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml; charset=UTF-8");
    post.addRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedCredentials);
    post.setRequestBody("<rest_access/>");
    try {
        System.out.println("Execute Basic Authentication request on " + endpoint);
        // Execute request
        int result = client.executeMethod(post);
```

But when I try to execute the above code, getting the 404 error

> "The requested resource (/caisd-rest/rest_access) is not available".

Can any one please help me how to find the REST URL for ca service desk whether it is common url for all like `/caisd-rest` or it is different. Here my infra team just installed the CA service desk. So do we need to do any other steps to provide rest access?

Answer (score 0):

Check in [CA Technologies](https://docops.ca.com/ca-service-management/14-1/en/reference/ca-service-desk-manager-reference-commands/technical-reference/rest-http-methods) Website, it should be `http://<host>:<REST port>/caisd-rest`

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, problem was that REST wasn't deployed properly, reconfiguring REST Service using this doc: [REST API reconfiguration](http://www.ca.com/us/services-support/ca-support/ca-support-online/knowledge-base-articles.tec598393.html) resolved the problem.

I folowed these steps:

1. Check for existence of *NX_ROOT/bopcfg/www/CATALINA_BASE_REST/webapps/caisd-rest*. If this directory does NOT exist, that's a very good indication that the REST deploy did not work properly.
2. Check for the errors in *NX_ROOT/log/jrest.log* file.
3. Try fix errors and redeploy REST Service using cmd:

   pdm_rest_util -undeploy
   pdm_rest_util -deploy